# C++ Pointers in 64bit instructions

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, jit, instructions

I'm writing a jit compiler (64bit only, windows). I need to access variables of the c++ program, by reference (pointer).

Example: Adding a 32bit integer from memory to a 32bit register, using this instruction:

```
opcode "03 /r" : ADD r32, m32. (valid in 64bit mode)
```

unfortunately this is asking for a 32bit displacement, but I (only?) have a 64bit pointer to the c++ variable.

My question: is there some way to get a 32bit displacement from a 64bit c++ pointer?

Or if not, more generally, how would I adress c++ variables?

I also tried to mov the pointer value to rax and use indirect adressing [rax]. Which doesn't seem to work either.

I've looked at some dis-assembly (clang), and it seems to use RIP (relative instruction pointer), such as

```
mov dword ptr [rip + test], 2358
```

Which seems odd, as rip changes on every instruction (as far as I know).

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Indirect adressing through, [rax], is working now! I had a bug in the c++. Still no luck with 32bit displacement adressing.

Comment: Why can you not use a 64-bit instruction?

Comment: 32bit integer or even 8bit instructions are perfectly valid and useful in 64bit mode. Only the pointers (memory adress) are 64bit .

Comment: This is not what I asked. I repeat: Why can you not use a 64-bit instruction?

Comment: Then I don't quite understand your question. You mean using a 64bit add instruction, such as

    REX.W + 03 /r ADD r64, r/m64

that would add a 64bit integer, no? I want to work with 32bit integers. That wouldn't solve my memory referencing problem.

Comment: why can't you put a 32-bit value into a 64-bit register and add two 64-bit registers? I'm missing something? If you do `mov eax, 12345678h` that automatically zero extends _EAX_ into the full 64-bit register _RAX_.

Comment: @DanyBittel That is clear now, that you do not want to use a 64-bit instruction.

Comment: I don't understand this question. There is no objection to loading a 32bit integer at a location indicated by a 64bit pointer, and in fact that is what `add r32, [m32]` does in 64bit mode, unless overridden with the 66 prefix.

Comment: @harold thanks harold, yes it's working now. I still don't understand how clang uses RIP and the adress though. I guess it's for the loader (to position the code on start up). I will work with [rax]..

Comment: The RIP deal relies on the .text section and wherever it wants to point to relocating together, which applies to static data. The offset you need changes based on where the instruction is yes, no big deal to compute the required offset though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer in the Intel Developer Manual vol 1 page 70:

*"Generally, displacements and immediates in 64-bit mode are not extended to 64 bits. They are still limited to 32 bits and sign-extended during effective-address calculations. In 64-bit mode, however, support is provided for 64-bit displacement and immediate forms of the MOV instruction."*

And in the Intel Instruction Set Reference Manual page 42:

*"In 64-bit mode, the ModR/M Disp32 (32-bit displacement) encoding is re-defined to be RIP+Disp32 rather than displacement-only. See Table 2-7."*

So disp32 can be used in 64bit mode only for relativ to instruction pointer adressing.

Comment: Or relative to a pointer in a general-purpose register, like `[rax + disp32]`, if you have a pointer to a struct and want to load a member.  Also, if you're accessing static data (e.g. global variables), you can use `[disp32]` addresses, because the "small" code model guarantees the addresses will be in the low 2GiB of virtual address space.  Putting your JIT-compiled code in the low 2GiB will let you use the normal `call` and `jmp` instructions to reach other code, which is a pretty big code-size advantage compared to `mov r64, imm64 / call r64`, because indirect jumps suck.

Comment: Unfortunatly, as far as I know, `[disp32]` only (to adress variables in the low 2gb) does not exist in 64bit mode. As you can see from the quote above `[disp32]` is interpreted as `[RIP + disp32]`.

Comment: In NASM syntax, use `[abs 0x1234]` to get an absolute encoding, even when the `DEFAULT rel` directive is in effect.  e.g. from objdump: `8b 04 25 34 12 00 00    mov    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x1234`, or `mov eax, [rel 0x1234]` assembles to `8b 05 72 11 c0 ff       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffc01172]        # 1234 <_start-0x3fee81>`

Comment: But anyway, I wasn't even talking about `[abs disp32]`, I was just commenting to say you can index into static data with `[disp32 + reg]`, which is a separate addressing mode from `[disp32]`.  Absolute disp32-only addressing takes more bytes because as the manual says, the standard 32bit encoding for no-register absolute addressing now encodes RIP-relative.  IIRC, the encoding for absolute addressing with no register in 64bit mode requires a SIB byte.

Comment: Anyway, you should use RIP-relative addressing for static data, because it's shorter to encode.  Just make sure you JIT into a buffer in the low 2G, which you'll want to anyway so you can use normal `call` insns.  **Yes, the relative offset changes every instruction, but you always know where the instruction is, so just do a subtract to calculate the offset from RIP while JIT-compiling.**